# Passing JavaScript variable to PHP using POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I read somewhere that you don't need a form or hidden value to pass data when using ajax. If I could even get an example I would be grateful.

index.js:

```
function collectData(r) { 
    //gets the rows index
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    //selects the row picked
    var sliceRow = document.getElementById('Sona').rows[i];
    //have access to indiviual cells in the row
    var sliceCell = sliceRow.cells;
    var song = (sliceCell[0].innerHTML);
    var artist = (sliceCell[1].innerHTML);
    $.post("myLibrary.php", { postsong: song, postartist: artist });
}
```

PHP file :

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $song = $_POST['postsong'];
    echo $song;
}
```

Comment: And what is not working, what error do you get?

Comment: What is your problem actually? can you state it clearly?

Comment: You will find an example on how to do it below the first sentence of your question.

Comment: I think it would get better with a get method.... instead.... I would still appreciate  an example of either or

Comment: I cant pass my variables postsong and postartist the php file isnt reading any of them

Comment: I got it to work with a get method thank you everyone I post it below for future readers

Comment: helpful link: http://www.coderslexicon.com/the-basics-of-passing-values-from-javascript-to-php-and-back/

Answer (score -1):

```
    $.ajax({
        url  : example.com', 
        contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        type : 'post',
        data : {
         i         : r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex,
         sliceRow  : document.getElementById('Sona').rows[i],
         sliceCell : sliceRow.cells,
         song      : (sliceCell[0].innerHTML),
         artist    : (sliceCell[1].innerHTML),
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // blabla
        }, 
    });


    <?php

    if(isset($_POST)) {
        print_r($_POST);
    }
```